# Propagate original assignment repository update to classroom repositories in Github Classroom

Tags: github

I was wondering if there is a way to propagate updates done to the original assignment repository to the repositories created by github classroom assignment invitation link?

Currently in the organization the structure is like this:

OriginalAssignmentRepo - contains code and readme.

PrivateStudenRepo-1 - contains student modifications to the code

PrivateStudenRepo-2

...

PrivateStudenRepo-x

When the original repository is updated, the changes is not automatically pushed to the student repos, and there are no commits added to these repos either. 
Is it really necessary to clone each of the student repos and push to it individually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to have a script that listens to [webhook events](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) from your original repo and to update each of the student repositories in whatever way necessary.

Comment: Thanks, this was something in the lines of what I was thinking about doing.T o be honest, I was just wondering if there already existed an automated way of doing this, or if there was a way to link the repositories. 

But this will solve it!